# How to fix a chain break?

Tags: arduino, mosfet, atmega328p

There is a task, there is a MOSFET transistor that should, on command from an Atmega328p, close the circuits and supply power, but is it possible to somehow check this circuit for closure without feeding a large current and voltage there to prevent triggering?
[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "check for closure"? Like any other component, if you don't apply a voltage across the drain-source pins of the MOSFET, no current flows. Also, are you **sure** you chose the right type of MOSFET and put it in the right way?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I mean, we need a way to check the circuit for its integrity, so as not to trigger the activation of the element that is connected to this contact.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "check for integrity", I know I'm being a bit thick here, but could you spell that out for me?

Comment: @MarcusMüller this means that I want to get information in some way that when the mosfet transistor is closed, the circuit will be closed and there is no further break

Comment: You are using vague words like integrity, large, triggering, element etc. You need to use specific values. For instance 'apply 2 V to load, and if it draws a current of > 10 uA then it's OK'. Note that loads like LEDs have a very non-linear voltage/current characteristic, so the best test then would be to apply a few uA to the load and to measure the voltage. Sometimes, loads can have components added specifically for the purpose of detection. If you say what the load is, and what it is meant to do, and not do, under what conditions, you may get an answer.

Comment: @Neil_UK well, look, the mosfet transistor is connected to the GND and VIN circuit (where it can be from 5 to 16 volts, with a current of up to 2.4 A), these contacts are closed in the normal position of the transistor, but when a signal is sent from atmega328p, it closes and the current flows through the circuit, which goes to the nichrome thread

Comment: The P-channel device shown is "always on". No checking is necessary.

Comment: The circuit you've drawn will never work as intended (as a switch). You're using the wrong kind of MOSFET (P-Channel instead of N-Channel) and/or have it connected upside-down (Source & Drain reversed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest connecting a resistor with a series LED between P1+ & P1-.  Select the R value to give a reasonable LED current for the voltage applied at VIN.  For example, if VIN=12V, and you want 1mA of LED current, then a resistor of 10K will be required.

The test you should apply will depend on what that circuit (Q1 and associated P1+, P1-) is intended to do.  If it is intended to drive just a small load of a few mA, such as an LED or small relay, then this test is OK.  However, if you intend to drive a heavy load, such as a nichrome heater wire that pulls maybe 2A, then you may want to select a test resistor  that can handle 12V and 1A, ie: 12W.

Careful: if the load is inductive, eg: a relay coil, then turning off the MOSFET will result in a large voltage spike delivered to the MOSFET Q1 which may destroy it.  You should consider putting some voltage suppression at P1-, for example, an anti-parallel diode (eg: 1N4004) connected with anode to P1-, cathode to P1+.